# How to refresh view with fetched data - Firestore & SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, combine

**Short:** The Images in my view are not updating after the first load. The URL remains the same as the previous loaded view, however the rest of the view that doesn't fetch a URL or data from storage is updated.

**Full:** I have two Views, a `ListView` and a `DetailView`.

In the `ListView` I display a list of type `List`. The detail view is supposed to show each `Profile` from `List.profiles`. I do this by storing each string `uid` in `List.profiles` and calling `model.fetchProfiles` to fetch the profiles for each list selected.

On the first selected `List` `model.fetchProfiles` returns the documents and `model.profiles` displays the data fine in the `DetailView`.

When first loading the `DetailView` the `ProfileRow` on appear is called and logs the profiles fetched. Then the `ProfileRow` loads the `imageURL` from the `imagePath` and uses it like to fetch the image.

**Console: Load List1**

> CARD DID APPEAR: Profiles []
> CARD DID APPEAR: SortedProfiles []
> CARD ROW
> CARD ROW DID APPEAR: Profiles profiles/XXXXXX/Profile/profile.png
> CARD ROW DID APPEAR: SortedProfiles profiles/XXXXXX/Profile/profile.png
> Get url from image path: profiles/XXXXXX/Profile/profile.png
> Image URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/APPNAME/profiles%XXXXXXX

When selecting the second `List` from `ListView` the `ProfileRow`  `didAppear` is not called due to;

```
if model.profiles.count > 0 {
  print("CARD ROW DID APPEAR: Profiles \(model.profiles[0]. imgPath)")     
  print("CARD ROW DID APPEAR: Sorted  \(model.sortedProfiles[0].imgPath)")
}
```

and won't ever again when selecting a `List` in `ListView`, however the rest of the profile data in the `ProfileRow` is displayed such as name so the data must be fetched.

The `ImagePath` is the same as the first view loading the exact same image. All other properties for the `Profile` such as name are loaded correctly.

**Console: Load List2**

> CARD DID APPEAR: Profiles []
> CARD DID APPEAR: SortedProfiles []
> CARD ROW
> Get url from image path: profiles/XXXXXX/Profile/profile.png
> Image URL:
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/APPNAME/profiles%XXXXXXX

If I then navigate to `List1` then the image for `List2` appears, if I reselect `List2` the image appears fine. The image show is correct on first load, and when selecting another list it always the one from before.

Can anyone help me out ?

**First View**

```
struct ListViw: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var model: Model

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
        
        ForEach(model.lists.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            NavigationLink(
                destination: DetailView()
                            .environmentObject(model)
                            .onAppear() {
                                model.fetchProfiles()
                            }
            ) {
                 ListRow(home:model.lists[index])
                    .environmentObject(model)
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
        }
    }
  }

}
```

**DetailView Card**

```
struct ProfilesCard: View {

@EnvironmentObject var model: Model

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 16) {                
            if !model.sortedProfiles.isEmpty {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 16) {
                    ForEach(model.sortedProfiles.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        ProfileRow(
                            name: "\(model.sortedProfiles[index].firstName) \(model.sortedProfiles[index].lastName)",
                            imgPath: model.sortedProfiles[index].imgPath,
                            index: index)
                            .environmentObject(model)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, 16)
            }
        
    }//End of Card
    .modifier(Card())
    .onAppear() {
        print("CARD DID APPEAR: Profiles \(model.profiles)")
        print("CARD DID APPEAR: SORTED \(model.sortedTenants)")
    }
}
}



struct ProfileRow: View {

@EnvironmentObject var model: Model

@State var imageURL = URL(string: "")

var name: String
var imgPath: String
var index: Int

private func loadImage() {
    print("load image: \(imgPath)")
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        fm.getURLFromFirestore(path: imgPath,  success: { (imgURL) in
                   print("Image URL: \(imgURL)")
            imageURL = imgURL
               }) { (error) in
                   print(error)
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12) {

                   KFImage(imageURL,options: [.transition(.fade(0.2)), .forceRefresh])
                       .placeholder {
                           Rectangle().foregroundColor(.gray)
                       }
                       .resizable()
                       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                       .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                       .cornerRadius(16)


                // Profile text is always displayed correctly
            Text(name)
                    .modifier(BodyText())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    .onAppear() {
        print("CARD ROW")

        // Crashes if check is not there
        if model.profiles.count > 0 {

            print("CARD ROW DID APPEAR: Profiles \(model.profiles[0]. imgPath)")

            print("CARD ROW DID APPEAR: Sorted  \(model.sortedProfiles[0].imgPath)")
        }
        
       loadImage()
    }
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Model: ObservableObject {

  init() {
      fetchData()
  }

  @Published var profiles: [Profile] = []
  var sortedProfiles: [Profile] {return profiles.removeDuplicates } 

  @Published var list: List? {
      didSet {
          fetchProfiles()
      }
  }

  func fetchData() {
    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
        
        email = currentUser.email!

            db.collection("lists")
                .whereField("createdBy", isEqualTo: currentUser.uid)
                .addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    return
                }

                self.lists = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> List? in
                    return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: List.self)
                }
            }

    }
 }

  func fetchProfiles() {
    profiles.removeAll()
    
    for p in list!.profiles {
        firestoreManager.fetchProfile(uid: t, completion: { [self] profile in
            profiles.append(profile)
        })
    }
  }

}
```

**Update**

What I have tried so far is to use `didSet` for the `ImgPath` or `ImgURL` but still not luck. Also have tried using `model.profiles` directly.

Answer (score 1):

In all callbacks with Firestore API make assignment for published or state properties on main queue, because callback might be called on background queue.

So, assuming data is returned and parsed correctly, here is as it should look like

```
for p in list!.profiles {
    firestoreManager.fetchProfile(uid: t, completion: { [self] profile in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           profiles.append(profile)
        }
    })
}
```

also I would recommend to avoid same naming for your custom types with SDK types - there might be very confusing non-obvious errors

```
// List model below might conflict with SwiftUI List
return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: List.self)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, however I found this behaviour to be similar to my new question,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231216/foreach-in-scrollview-not-updating-until-interaction

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge its not the problem from firebase end, because the ones data fetched the new data is updated. You are facing problem of image caching. Caching is a technique that stores a copy of a given resource. So when the image is loaded for first time it get cached and whenever you are reloading images are displayed from cache instead of loading from URL. This is done for more network usage.

You can programatically clear cache by adding following code before your image loading.

Alamofire uses NSURLCache in the background so you just have to call:

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Update for Swift 4.1

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Comment: I hope this might solve your problem. If you still have some problems you can reach me out here