# ForEach in ScrollView not updating until interaction

Tags: swiftui, combine

When adding to or removing from an array, the view does not update unless the user interacts with the `ScrollView`.

The `Model` is a `ObservableObject` that is declared as a `StateObject` early in the app lifecycle and then passed as a `EnvironmentObject`.

The data is simply a custom `Profile` object with an array of objects, when adding to `store.profile!.tasks.append()` or removing from the view does not update unless the user scrolls the ScrollView; I mean literally by 1 pixel.

What I have tried

- Wrapping the ForEach in a LazyVStack or VStack
- Wrapping the NavigationLink in a VStack
- Making sure size is full height incase it needed to recalculate

**Code**

```
class Profile: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable
    var tasks: [Task]
}


struct Task: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable {
    var createdBy: String
    var title: String
    var date: Date
}

class Store : ObservableObject {
    @Published var profile: Profile?
}

struct ListView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var store: Store

  var body: some View {
     GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
          ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
              ForEach(store.profile!.tasks.filter({ return $0.createdBy == store.profile!.uid}).indices, id: \.self) { index in
                 NavigationLink(destination: DetailView().environmentObject(store)) {
                      TasksRow().id(UUID()) 
                 }
             }
          }
           .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width, alignment: .center)
           .frame(maxHeight: geometry.size.height)
           .background(Color.gray)
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Profile` is a reference type, so when you append task in it the reference to profile is not changed, so published does not work.

Use instead value type for profile (ie. `struct`)

```
struct Profile: Identifiable, Codable, Equatable
    var tasks: [Task]
}
```

now appending task to profile will change profile itself, the publisher send event and view will refresh.